# Crystal report filter by daily, weekly and month in vb.net, ms access as the database

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

it will be my first time asking here so I hope you will be easy on me ^_^

I am making a program where I can generate report by daily, monthly and weekly using crystal report in vb.net. My daily reports are all set but I was confused on how to do it in weekly and monthly. I am using 2 datetimepicker, one for the 1st day of the month and the other is for the last day.

```
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TITO WHERE [_DATE] between'" + DateTimePicker1.Text + " AND " + DateTimePicker2.Text + "'", con)
    Dim ds As New DataTable
    da.Fill(ds)

    CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{TITO._DATE} IN DateValue (" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & " ) TO DateValue (" & DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & " )"

    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    con.Close()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKitT.png)
here is my code for reference. I getting errors like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g9vz.png)

please help,

Comment: I would start by changing your query expression to using parameters, looking at the error message it looks like you’ve got some type casting issues when creating the sql command, using parameters avoids this

Comment: And because you’re new.  There are two sure fire ways to get cut down on this site and you’ve done both.  1) not formatting your code, the site has a preview for a reason. 2) images of errors

Comment: I change it to this    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TITO WHERE [_DATE] between'" + DateTimePicker1.Text + " AND " + DateTimePicker2.Text + "'", con)

Comment: and for the selection formula to this     CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{TITO._DATE} IN DateValue (" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & " ) TO DateValue (" & DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & " )"

Comment: And there you have probably the 3rd, 4th and 5th sure fire ways to get cut down.  3) Don't flood comments with code.  Edits your question with the appropriate updated info.  4) Mishmash of types.  If you are storing dates use Dates, don't do any sort of date  <-> string conversions and 5)  When people offer help and or suggestions in comments, don't just brush it off and ignore it.  First comment I made was use command parameters, don't concatenate strings.  It makes for a much more robust and maintainable solution